# In Excel, how can I automatically fill value in multiple columns based on contents of another sheet?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

How can I  fill multiple columns in excel based on the contents of another spreadsheet? I have tried using `VLOOKUP`, but I'm not sure how I can automatically fill multiple columns based on another sheet.

I have a sheet which looks like this:

[image: Spreadsheet with 4 columns]

In another spreadsheet, I would like to find a way to automatically record

1. whether the user name it taken through binary code of 1/0, and
2. the name of the person the code is taken by.

This is the type of sheet I am trying to create:

[image: spreadsheet with columns, username, status and name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Status column, cell B2, put:

```
=MIN(1, IFNA(MATCH(A2, Sheet1!B:B,0), 0))
```

In the Name column, cell C2, put:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!B:B, 0)), "")
```

Copy the formulas down...

If you have many more columns to fill like that, then it becomes interesting to only perform the `MATCH`-operation once. In that case, create a hidden column (let's say at Z) where you put in cell Z2:

```
=MATCH(A2, Sheet1!B:B,0)
```

...and then use that result of Z2 in the other columns. So, at B2:

```
=MIN(1, IFNA(Z2, 0))
```

...and at C2:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, Z2), "")
```

Comment: Corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help @trincot. For cell C2, it copies the username of Sheet 1 but not the name. How can I change the code so the name is matched?.